# In AWS IAM, how do you write a policy to allow all actions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've read the [AWS IAM example policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html) but don't see an example for allowing a group to do everything.

I'm trying:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: The policy generator spits out an `Sid` parameter, no idea if it's required. I believe some highly privileged actions have to be specifically called out as they're not included in *.

Comment: You need the version tag ("Version": "2012-10-17") as well.

Comment: @Guy - that works - I needed it at the same level as the Statement. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the version tag (`"Version": "2012-10-17"`) as well like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```